# Ajax .change() is not working with mutiple select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Im trying to do an order system. And i want to use a jQuery code with my system.

Here is my orders.php page, this page shows all new orders.

```
While loop starts,

Order id - order Date - price - options

   1     - 29.03.13   - $120  - [Problem Start Here in Options ]

While Loop Ends
```

And my options code is here :

```
    <select id="ManageOrders">
        <option>ManageOrders</option>
        <option value="orders.php?AcceptOrder=<?=$id;?>">Accept This Order</option>
        <option value="orders.php?RejectOrder=<?=$id;?>">Reject This Order</option>
        <option value="orders.php?EditOrder=<?=$id;?>">Edit This Order</option>
        <option value="orders.php?MarkAsDelivered=<?=$id;?>">Mark As Delivered</option>             
    </select>
```

And my jquery codes :

```
$("#ManageOrders").change(function()
{
document.location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

What is my problem ? = Problem is this select is working with first order, but with multiple orders only first row is working, others doesnt working...

Try This : http://jsfiddle.net/TrzU7/2/

First is working but second or third isnt working

Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firts: Id Must be unique.

try to change it to class like:

```
<select class="ManageOrders">

 $(".ManageOrders").change(function()
 {
    document.location.href = $(this).val();
 });
```

[Live Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/TrzU7/3/)

Comment: hehehehe don't worry.